# Grantha in order to learn Sanskrit

Tags: scripture, sanskrit, language, writing-system

From a family of southern Tamil descent is it easier to learn Grantha to learn to write and learn Sanskrit or traditional Devanagari. This is a language question, but it is for religious reading help, so...